# Browser update element takes long when looping array of 2000 elements with new values

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am refactoring my code so my search mechanism search results with will get results from ajax/json. But by doing this browser seems to stopped responding(Current page tab only) until the data is populated in `select` tag

Here is what i am doing.

```
for (i = 0; i < jsonData["outlet"].length; i++) {
         outlet.innerHTML += "<option value=" + jsonData["outlet"][i] + ">" + jsonData["outlet"][i] + "</option>";
    }
```

Lenght of those json data are around 2000

Comment: 2000 should not be a matter at all.

Comment: Are you sure this code is what causes the page to be slow? try to remove it, or try to lower 2000 to a small number and check if it made any change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buffer it all in memory in a string. This is relatively fast.

Then,when the string is complete output it to the HTML.

In your current code you are forcing a graphics reflow with every iteration. Every iteration the page has to recalculate the entire page layout. This costs a lot of cpu cycles.

```js
function getBuffer(jsonData) {
        var buffer = [];
        for (i = 0; i < jsonData["outlet"].length; i++) {
                 buffer[i] = "<option value=" + jsonData["outlet"][i] + ">" + jsonData["outlet"][i] + "</option>";
            }
        return buffer.join('');
    }
    var jsonData = {outlet:["foo","bar","baz"]};
    for(flood = 3;flood<10000;flood++) {
        jsonData.outlet[flood] = 'fooding '+flood;
    }
    var outlet = document.getElementById('outlet');
    outlet.innerHTML = getBuffer(jsonData);
```

```html
<select id="outlet"></select>
```